# A Thing, made of things, which makes many things

Tags: riddle, word

> I am a thing, which is used to make things.
>   I am made of things.
>   You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.
>   You give me your idea, I give you your product.

Hint #1:

> I make things hot to make your idea,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you a

> 3D printer?

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> Self explanatory

I am made of things.

> Some are made of 3d printed components, creating a never ending line of self-replicating robots!

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> Whilst growing in popularity, they're still not widespread consumer items

You give me your idea, I give you your product.

> You feed it a design file, it spits out a physical object

Comment: You did it, well done. As you can see, I have absolutely no ideas or any sort of imagination when coming up with these things. But well done, none the less.

Comment: I actually guessed this puzzle correctly before looking at the spoiler text! (that rarely happens) - Happy! Happy!

Comment: @JohnyNich You posted a riddle which got lots of answers, some of which were wrong - that's definitely not the same thing as having absolutely no ideas!

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

> A 3D printer

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> A 3D printer create things

I am made of things.

> A 3D printer is made of other pieces

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> It's a recent technology so not everybody has seen one.

You give me your idea, I give you your product.

> You introduce a file with your idea (design) and it prints a 3D replica of it!

I make things hot to make your idea

> It melts the plastic (usually a polimer) and after heating it to make it more liquid it cools down the plastic to give it form!

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Laser Sintering 3d Printer?

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> Exists to make other things

I am made of things.

> It's a machine, made of various components.

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> This type of 3d printer is very expensive, and rather dangerous, most people would only have experience with other varieties; and 3d printers in general are still somewhat rare.

You give me your idea, I give you your product.

> You put in blueprints, out comes an object.

I make things hot to make your idea,

> Works by heating things with Lasers until they fuse

Comment: Damn, my father took the computer and u solved it before I can post my answer :(

Answer (score 2):

My guess

> An industrial machine.

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> Explanatory

I am made of things.

> Explanatory

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> They're quite rare (unless you visit certain places).

You give me your idea, I give you your product.

> There are machines which you just have to feed in the specs and they make the product

I make things hot to make your idea

> Machines heat stuff while melting something or to weld something.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> An anvil? Or a forge?

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> Ill stick with the anvil idea for explanations - An anvil is used to make metal things

I am made of things.

> Atoms

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> Doubt many but forge workers have seen anvils

You give me your idea, I give you your product.

> Thats it's job

Also fits the hint

> It heats metal to form them into things

Comment: Looks like we've missed the answer.

Comment: The second guess fits the hint better than the first. The first is just for hammering, the second is where the heating is done.

Comment: I had different reasoning, but your second is what I would answer and argue with as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> A Welding Machine

I am a thing, which is used to make things.

> Self Explanatory

I am made of things.

> Made of electric arc and metal

You may have seen me in my life, but I am quite rare.

> Not found everywhere

You give me your idea, I give you your product:

> Idea here is AC/DC settings

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add explanation of why you think it's correct, otherwise it may be removed.